# Relating degree of projective varieties and a finite morphism between them

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite, dominant morphism of projective varieties. I suspect that $\deg(f)\cdot\deg(Y)=\deg(X)$ always holds, where $\deg(f)=[K(X):K(Y)]$. If required, we may assume that $X$ and $Y$ are projective over an algebraically closed field (of characteristic zero even). My question is whether this is true and if so, I would love to have a reference.

Comment: What is the degree of an abstract variety? 

Comment: I don't know, but these are projective varieties.

Comment: I might still explain what I mean by $\deg(X)$: It is $\dim(X)!$ times the leading coefficient of the Hilbert Polynomial of its homogeneous coordinate ring. For hypersurfaces $X=Z(f)$ and $f$ an element of degree $d$, one can show that $d=\deg(X)$. This is about all the intuition I have about degrees of projective varieties, maybe someone else can shed some more light.

Comment: The homogeneous coordinate ring is not a property of a projective variety; it is a property of an embedding of a projective variety into projective space. In particular, the same variety can embed into projective space via embeddings of different degrees. 

Comment: A simple example of what can go wrong is to let $X = Y = \mathbb{P}^1$ but to embed the first copy as a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and to embed the second copy via an isomorphism in $\mathbb{P}^1$. Then the "degree" of $X$ is $2$, the "degree" of $Y$ is $1$, and there is an isomorphism $f : X \to Y$ which therefore has degree $1$. 

Comment: This is one of those horrible oriented/orientable distinctions that crops up for e.g. spin manifolds (are they spinnable, or spun?) and Frobenius split varieties (are they splittable, or splut?). Qiaochu, do you have a name for a subvariety of projective space?

Comment: Wow, thanks for clarifying that, I always thought that degree was completely intrinsic. I am now wondering: I can certainly choose an embedding of minimal degree - does that always yield degree one or could we define a degree for abstract projective varieties this way?

Comment: I have a strong sense that any variety of degree one is linear, hence isomorphic to some projective space; but at the moment, I'm only sure of this for complete intersections (hence hypersurfaces).

Comment: Actually, this result is stated in Hartshorne, Exercise I.7.6.

Comment: Well then ... is it a meaningful notion to take the minimum of all degrees of embeddings into projective space?

Comment: A note here, since you asked for intuition on the notion of degree (for non-hypersurfaces).  If $X$ is a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $d$, then degree of $X$ is the number of points at which $X$ intersects a generic linear space $L \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n-d$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This  is not  true in general.

In fact, let $H_X$ be a hyperplane section of $X$ and $H_Y$ be a hyperplane section of $Y$, with respect to the fixed embeddings $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^M$. Then

$\deg X= (H_X)^n, \quad \deg Y =(H_Y)^n$,

where $n= \dim X = \dim Y$.

Now requiring

$\deg X = (\deg f) \cdot \deg Y \quad (*)$

is equivalent to require $(H_X)^n=(\deg f) \cdot (H_Y)^n$. This is true for instance if the map $f \colon X \to Y$ is induced by a subsystem of the complete linear system $|H_X|$, otherwise it is false in general.

For instance, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ be the Veronese surface and $Y=\mathbb{P}^2$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, there is a map $f \colon X \to Y$ of degree $1$, but $\deg X=4$ and $\deg Y=1$.

Analogously, let us consider $X=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. Then $X$ is a quadric and any $2$-dimensional, base-point free subsystem of the complete linear system $|H_X|$ induces a finite morphism  $f \colon X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ of degree $2$, so in this case $(*)$ is satisfied. However, you can compose $f$ with any isomorphism $g \colon X' \to X$, where $X' \subset \mathbb{P}^N$ is a Segre embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ with $N >3$, obtaining a map $f' \colon X' \to \mathbb{P}^2$ of degree $2$ which does not satisfy $(*)$, since $\deg X' >2$.

Comment: Thanks very much, the last example made Qiaochu Yan's point perfectly clear.